# Change Windows explorer font size

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, fonts

I'd like to increase the font size in Windows Explorer. By default it's very small, and I don't really like that for navigating folders and finding files.

Here's what it looks like by default:

[image]

When I change the font-size to *Medium (125%)* in *Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display*:

[image]

*(To best see the differences, open the images above in new tabs as they are scaled when shown on this page.)*

The problem is that increasing the font size to *Medium* affects everything, and some things just look very odd at that size, like icon captions, title bars and things like that.

Is there a way to change the font size for Windows Explorer only?

Comment: AFAIK, the only ways to change it is to change the icon font size for the Windows GUI or the DPI setting.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/change-the-font-windows-xp-displays-in-windows-explorer-100566/

1. Access the Display Properties dialog box by right-clicking the desktop and selecting the Properties command.
2. Select the Appearance tab and click the Advanced button.
3. Select the "Icon" entry from the Item drop-down list.
4. Use the Font drop-down arrow to select a font from the list.
5. Click OK twice — once to close the Advanced Appearance dialog box and once to close the Display Properties dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can solve this problems.
A. You can increase/decrease the screen resolutions to make things appears bigger or smaller on the screen. For that please refer this link 
[How to change the Screen resolution in Windows 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7wEkl9sdQo)

[How to Change Screen Resolution in Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GdKiUAnyHc)

B. Change the font and appearance setting in the Internet Options in control panel or Internet Explorer. 
[Change the font size of Internet explorer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIKtwOWrKC0)

[Change font size of Internet explorer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oouqBwl4t9I)

C. Third option is that you can use accessibility features available in windows like Zoom features.
[How to zoom in/out in Windows 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5Zvc4ByYro)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Windows 10 Settings (shortcut: Win + I)
2. Ease of Access->Display
3. Make text bigger OR Make everything bigger

Comment: Thanks. It is great that MS have offered this without increasing the screen resolution, however, there is no proper space padding accordingly at least in Windows Explorer. So, if you increase the fonts, it just jumbles up the whole display without no proper spaces between them.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, open Explorer and paste "Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization" into the address bar.  Then click on Windows Color (the 2nd of 4 items along the bottom of the screen).  The "Window Color and Appearance" box will then appear.

Under "Item", select "Icon".  You don't need to touch the icon size.  In the bottom row, however, you can select what is in your opinion the most readable font available on your system, and set it to a size you can read easily from a comfortable distance.

My own choice, if you want to try it out, is "Segoe UI Semibold" in 14 point.

Windows 10 may not have this functionality, or may work differently.

NB:  Using a Windows Classic theme will make your UI look like Windows XP.  Which is pretty cool, actually, because you can pick all your colours and fonts to your taste, and appreciate anew XP's neat, classic look.

NB, also:  The "Window Color and Appearance" box can be used to change the size and colour of just about anything on your computer.  However, it's a little weird to use.  Rules to bear in mind (which took me a very long time to figure out):

- "Disabled Item" and "Menus fonts" are always the same.
- Colours of "3D Objects" and "Caption Buttons" symbols are always the same.
- Font colours of "Message Box" and "Window" are always the same, and their font settings also apply to "3D Objects" and possibly your browser's address and search bars.
- Changing the "3D Objects" background settings resets just about everything else ("Application Background", "Disabled Item", "Inactive Title bar", and "Menu color"), so if you want to change the "3D Objects" settings, do that FIRST.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You can't change the text size for only File Explorer.

Comment: ar you can, in windows 7.  see other answers. but how to do it in W10